# WPF DataGrid не работает StringFormat

Tags: wpf, datetime, datagrid

из базы MS Access берется значение из столбца "Дата и время" которое записано в  виде 01.01.2000

```
<DataGrid x:Name="log_grid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding }"
    ....

    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата рожд."
            Binding="{Binding birthdate, StringFormat='{}{0: dd.MM.yyyy}'}"
        />
</DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

выводит 01.01.2000 0:00:00. как вывести дату согласно формату?

Comment: `StringFormat=d`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нет. добавил пару слов в вопрос

Comment: Что нет-то? У вас `birthdate` какой тип имеет? `DateTime` или `string`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "Дата и время" в конструкторе. База MS Access

Comment: WPF не привязывается сразу к базе, обычно создается класс, который содержит свойства, идентичные базе и он задается в привязке. `birthdate` у вас скорей всего также является свойством одного из класса.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ правильно говорят что правильно заданный вопрос это половина ответа. Datagrid заполняется `ObservableCollection<logGridItem>`. `new logGridItem(){ birthdate =  dr["birthdate"].ToString()}`

Comment: Вооот `birthdate` у вас является строкой (ибо делаете `.ToString()`), тогда в этот `.ToString()` и пишите нужный формат (что то вроде `.ToString("n")`). Ну а вообще, сделайте нормальный класс, где дата будет не в `string`, а в `DateTime`!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106634/discussion-between-axmed2004-and-evgeniyz).